# Norm of the operator $(x_n)_n \mapsto (\sum_k a^k x_{n+k}/k!)_n$ in $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\ell^1$ be the space of absolutely summable real sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with standard norm
$$
\|(x_n)_n\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|.
$$
Let $A$ be the operator in $\ell^1$ given by
$$
A(x_n)_n = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!} x_{n+k} \right)_n
$$
for some constant $a > 0$. It is clear that $A$ is bounded, because
$$
\|A(x_n)_n\| = \sum_n \left| \sum_k \frac{a^k }{k!} x_{n+k} \right| \le \sum_k \frac{a^k}{k!} \sum_n |x_{n+k}| \le \|(x_n)_n\| \sum_k \frac{a^k}{k!} = \|(x_n)_n\| e^a
$$
and
$$
\|A\| \le e^a.
$$

> What is the norm of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $(x_n)=\frac 1 N(1,1,..,1,0,0,...)$ where there are $N$ $1$'s. Then $\|A(x_n)\|=\frac 1 N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac {a^{k}} {k!}(N-k) =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac {a^{k}} {k!}(\frac {N-k} N )$. An Application of DCT shows that $\|A(x_n)\| \to e^{a}$ as $N  \to \infty$. Hence $\|A\|=e^{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_n=(1,1,\dots,1,0,0,0,\dots,0,\dots)$ where we have $n$ aces at first. Then $Ae_n=(\sum_{k=0}^n a^k/k!, \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^k/k!,\dots, a+1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$ so

$$\|Ae_n\|_{\ell^1}=1+(1+a)+(1+a+a^2/2!)+(1+a+a^2/2!+a^3/3!)+\dots+(1+a+a^2/2!+\dots+a^n/n!) $$
$$=(n+1)\cdot 1+ n\cdot a+ (n-1)\cdot a^2/2!+(n-2)\cdot a^3/3!+\dots 2\cdot a^{n-1}/(n-1)!+a^n/n!$$
Now $\|A\|\geq\|Ae_n\|/\|e_n\|$ for all $n$ and $\|e_n\|=n$ obviously, so

$$\|A\|\geq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n-k+1)a^k}{k!\cdot n}.$$

Now this limsup on the right is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!}=e^a$. This is seen with measure theoretic arguments: the sum is nothing but the integral over $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to the counting measure, so you can apply the monotone convergence theorem. I'm sure there are numerous other justifications of why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(n,k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,k)$ when $f(n,k)\geq0$ for all $n,k$.